# How to show a "popup" Ionic View whilst maintaining background state?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to show a fully-fledged view with controller on my Ionic app, except it needs to pop up on top of my current open view, with the currently open view in the background.

Once it pops up, I want to be able to navigate from that view to another view, all within the popup, without affecting the background view.

How can I do this?